# What IEnumerable<IEnumerable<>> means?

Tags: c#

Some methods in c# that i have seen , requires `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<"some class">>`. When method need  `IEnumerable<"some class">` as a parameter , i can pass a one-dimensional array or list . I thought by the same logic i can pass two-dimensional array as `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<"some class">>` , but my compiler says it is not the same. What data types i can pass to such methods, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` is an enumeration of an enumeration of integers.

https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/213/using-c-linq---a-practical-overview/ienumerablet

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1

It means that each element of the root list is a list of int.

If we write:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> listOfLists = GetItems();
```

We can parse items like that:

```
foreach ( var list in listOfLists )
{
  Console.WriteLine("Values");
  foreach ( var value in list )
    Console.WriteLine("    " + value);
}
```

In fact if we declare:

```
var items = new List<List<int>>();
```

This is a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>` here.

It is like an array of arrays of int:

```
var items = int[][];
```

Here it is not a multidimentionnal array but a jagged array:

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-jagged-array

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/jagged-arrays-in-C-Sharp-net

Answer (score -1):

IEnumerable is just an interface, which is implemented by a lot classes/types, two of which the List and Array (you can find the list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netcore-3.1)).

So, as as example, when the compiler tells you must pass a IEnumerable<"some class"> parameter it can be, for instance a List (depending if the "some class" refers to a string... if it refers to a class Car created by you then you must pass a List...) or string[] (which is an array of strings, which also implements this interface).
If you have to pass a IEnumerable<IEnumerable<"some class">> that means you have to have to layers of objects which implement the IEnumerable interface. You can have things like:
List<List>
string[][]

And others...

Answer (score -2):

Long story short, it’s an interface that allows you to do a foreach loop on certain objects.